# python3: can't open file [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, github, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to host a discord bot through google through the Linux command line. I am using it through Github and a virtual environment but I think I am doing something wrong.  I am a complete noob. here are the commands I am running. Any help would be much appreciated

`git clone https://github.com/MrPlum111/discord-bot-repo`
then I input my username and password

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
python3 bot.py
```

bot.py is the name of the file in GitHub

Comment: You need to change directory to the folder containing the `bot.py` file. So `cd discord-bot-repo` and then `python3 bot.py` (or better:) `python3 -m bot`

Comment: so what would the order of commands be?

Comment: After `source venv/bin/activate`, change directory `cd discord-bot-repo` and run `python bot.py`